# Can WCF be used to have a REST API URL like http://yourhost.com/{service-contract}.{binding}?op={target-method}?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm wondering if I can use WCF so that the client can set the appropriate binding by just changing the URL.  Some examples:

URL: http://yourhost.com/orders.json?op=getall
Description: get all orders as JSON.

URL:  http://yourhost.com/orders.xml?op=getall
Description: get all orders as XML.

URL: http://yourhost.com/orders.soap?op=getall
Description: get all orders as SOAP that's WSI compliant.

URL: http://yourhost.com/orders.soap?wsdl=yes
Description: shows the WSDL of the SOAP service.

This strategy is somewhat similar to what Twitter had used in it's API.

Is this possible with WCF?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than have the user specify it via the URL, have them specify:
- the request via the content-type header
- the response via the accept header.

Wcf 4 will automatically serialize/deserialize as requested.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476510.aspx

Now, you just have one URL that they interact with, and let Wcf handle the rest based on the incoming headers.

You would need a separate endpoint for the SOAP stuff, though.